# MongoDB Mapreduce: query/restriction/filter on result of mapreduce?

Tags: mongodb, filter, mapreduce

In querying a mongoDB database with map_reduce, I need to limit the actual results. I was hoping to use the `query` option but this only restricts data in the `map` part. I need to restrict output.

My data looks like this (left other attributes out):

```
 obj1: { name: "obj1", version: 1, someAttr = "a" }, 
 obj1a: { name: "obj1", version: 2, someAttr= "b"},

 obj2: { name: "obj2", version: 1 }, 
 obj2a: { name: "obj2", version: 2} ...
```

I have objects who share the same `name` per version (which is incremented per update).

I need to get the **newest version** of each object, and I have written map/reduce functions (it's done in mongomapper):

**MAP:**

```
function() {
  emit(this.name, this);
}
```

**REDUCE:**

```
function(key, values) {
  var res = values[0];
  for(var i=1; i<values.length; i++)
  {
    if(values[i].version >res.version)
    {
      res = values[i];
    }
  }
  return res;
}
```

Now from time to time I need to restrict results and I juse the `query` option for that. IT works fine, except in one use case:

**I need the latest version of obj1 that has also `someAttr` set to `"a"`.**

So what I tried in `query` is:

```
name: "obj1", someAttr: "a"
```

The **expected outcome** is an **empty result** because the latest version does not have `someAttr` set to `"a"`. What I got is obj1 with version 1...

How can I restrict the **output** to only those objects with `someAttr` set to `"a"`?

Comment: Have you considered using the Aggregation framework instead of a MapReduce? You could use your query to filter, and then `$sort` by version and `$limit` to one result.

Comment: @WiredPrairie the framework I'm actually using is a Ruby framework called mongomapper. It doesn't really support the aggregation framework. Also, I need to have the highest version of **each** object in a single collection, not just the one result.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand your data. The aggregation framework could return each object (grouped by `name` for example). You can use `MongoMapper.database.command` and pass in `'aggregate'` and the pipeline.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add to your reduce function

```
function(key, values) {
  var res = values[0];
  for(var i=1; i<values.length; i++)
  {
    if(values[i].version >res.version)
    {
      res = values[i];
    }
  }
  if ('someAttr' in res && res.someAttr == "a")
  return res;
}
```

Or if you want to check for the latest version between just the ones that have someAttr set to 'a' you can do

```
function(key, values) {
  var res = {version : 0}
  for(var i=0; i<values.length; i++)
  {
    if('someAttr' in res && res.someAttr == "a" && values[i].version >res.version)
    {
      res = values[i];
    }
  }
  return res;
}
```

Comment: You took it way too literally, it has to be dynamic. It needs to be like a where query where I specify what attribute has what value. But map/reduce doesn't take parameters.

Comment: Map reduce takes parameters through scope. You can check it out [here](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.mapReduce/#db.collection.mapReduce)

Comment: You just add scope { someAttr : "a" } to your mapreduce request (alongside your query e.g { query : { ... } , scope : { ... }) and then you can use the someAttr as a variable inside your javascript mapreduce code.

Comment: That's a great suggestion!